# C#: How to initialize a generic list via reflection?

Tags: list, reflection, generics

I have a list of object properties read from xml file and want to create the object through reflection (not xml serialization). For example, I have a property

```
List<Employee> Employees { get; set; }
```

I want to initialize this list from the follwing xml file:

```
<Employees>
  <Employee>
    <FirstName>John</FirstName>
    <LastName>Zak</LastName>
    <Age>20</Age>
  </Employee>
</Employees>
```

I could create the Employees object dynamically though e.g.

```
  Type employees = (type of Employees through reflection)
  object obj = Activator.CreateInstance(employees);
```

My problem is how can I populate the Employees list? I want to do it in a generic way (no cast to Employee) to make this code reusable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, this should do (`employees` and `obj` variables are from your code):

```
var employee = BuildEmployeeFromXml();
employees.GetMethod("Add").Invoke(obj, new[] {employee});
// repeat the above for as many employee objects you have
Console.WriteLine(list);
```

The code assumes you already know how to build the `employee` object from the XML in the `BuildEmployeeFromXml()` method.  If you don't, refer to my library [Fasterflect](http://fasterflect.codeplex.com/) for quick & easy way to construct objects using reflection.

Comment: I think this is what I'm looking for. I'll try it out. Thank for pointing me to your Fasterflect which seems to be very interesting. By the way, do you have an idea how to initialize an array? for exmple, Employee[] instead of List<Employee>?

Comment: I assume you asked how to initialize an array using reflection.  Look at Array.CreateInstance() method http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.array.createinstance.aspx.  For example, calling Array.CreateInstance(elementType, 10) creates an array of 10 elements whose type is elementType.

Answer (score 0):

Why use Reflection?

This is something that the [XmlSerializer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.serialization.xmlserializer.aspx) should be able to handle for you.

<strike>LINQ to XML is also a possibility (especially if you're coding to a changing XML document). The code used to construct an object from XML with LINQ to XML is better suited to handle changes in the XML format.</strike>

Nevermind...LINQ to XML isn't going to help you if you're targeting .NET 2.0.

Comment: The reason for not using XmlSerializer is that it's a convertion project. The object's interface has been changed.

Comment: @miliu - I'm still not understanding the issue. Reading an object from XML via Reflection should really be a last ditch effort. You might also want to check out LINQ to XML...

Comment: We are normally using XmlSerializer. However, in this case, we want to convert the xml file created in app v1.0 and use it in app v2.0. I don't understand how LINQ to XML can help. Actually, XmlSerializer is using reflection, right? What's wrong with that?

Comment: I didn't mean using .NET 1.0 or 2.0. It's my app version. We are using .NET 3.5. So, how LINQ to XML can help? Essentially, we want to be able to create an object based on outdated xml file. Most of the properties are same, but some are changed.